# how put html required attribute in jsp page

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am using bootstrap to my jsp page. Also jsp taglibs.

Here is my input feild code.

```
<form:form path="password" cssClass="form-control"
                                  required data-bv-notempty-message="The password is required and cannot be empty"
                                   data-bv-identical="true" data-bv-identical-field="confirmPassword" data-bv-identical-message="The password and its confirm are not the same"
                                   data-bv-different="true" data-bv-different-field="username" data-bv-different-message="The password cannot be the same as username"/>
```

when I deploid the war app it get this error in browser.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/sign_up.jsp (line: 44, column: 44) equal symbol expected
```

how put I required attribute in JSP???

Comment: `required="true"` have tried like this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this way and everything works just fine.

```
<form:input path="projectName" class="form-control" required='true' placeholder="Enter Project name" />
```